# jQuery .click.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a code, where there is a plus (+) image. When you click it, it rotates, until rotation is 45° (x). I am making it through `toggleClass` ... Now, i have about 7 of those images, but this click event is running ONLY for the first one, why? i tried `each` function, but still same.. totally lost...

there is the code for jQuery:

```
$("#plus_x").each(function() {
$(this).on("click", function(){
                console.log("CLICK!");
                $(this).toggleClass("box_rotate box_transition");
                $("#item").hasClass("open-panel") 
                    ? ($("#item").delay(250).animate({height: '75px'}),  
                        $("#item").removeClass("open-panel"))

                    : ($("#item").delay(250).animate({height: "300px"}), 
                        $("#item").addClass("open-panel"));
            });
    });
```

here's HTML:

```
    <div id="timeline">
                <div id="item" style="border-left: 4px solid #8E44AD;">
                    <div id="date">
                        <h1>31. 5.</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="plus">
                        <img id="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="item">
                    <div id="date">
                        <h1>31. 5.</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="plus">
                        <img id="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="item">
                    <div id="date">
                        <h1>31. 5.</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="plus">
                        <img id="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="item">
                    <div id="date">
                        <h1>31. 5.</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="plus">
                        <img id="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and css..:

```
#item{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #464646;
}

    .item_roll{
        height: 275px;
    }

.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
         transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.box_transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}

#date{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#plus{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    padding: 22.5px;
}
```

Hope, you now have maximum information to fix my problem. Of corse, [THERE is link to my website](http://david.addagio.cz/gospel/aktualne.html), so at the bottom of the page, check that out, try it... Please help me

Thanks

NOTE!

Looks pretty weird in Edge, don't know why....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` attribute in HTML must have unique values, you cannot repeat the same `id` value for different elements like you do.

To solve this, replace these `id="plus_x"` attributes by `class="plus_x"` and do your `each` on `$(".plus_x")` selector.

However, you have the same problem with other `id` properties with values `item`, `date` and `plus`, so you need to also solve that in a similar way, also in you CSS.

Finally, for your purpose it is not necessary to do a `each`, as you can define a click handler for all matches in one go. You'll need to find the `.item` belonging to the clicked item, which you can do with `.closest()`:

```
$(".plus_x").on("click", function(){
    console.log("CLICK!");
    $(this).toggleClass("box_rotate box_transition");
    // get ancestor that has "item" class:
    var $item = $(this).closest(".item");
    $item.delay(250).animate({
        height: $item.hasClass("open-panel") ? '75px' : '300px'
    });
    $item.toggleClass("open-panel");
});
```

Comment: I didn't knew that! I know that it's a bad to put multiple id but I didn't know that it affects jquery. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I made some further comments in my answer, which should help you find the correct `item` in your click handler.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you declared the same ID (`'plus_x'`) for several elements. The `'click'` handler is applied to the first element with that ID and the others are ignored. You can target only one element by its ID.

To fix this, change the id attribute declaration for the `<img>` elements to a class attribute declaration:

```
<img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
```

Then, change the selector to target all the elements with that class:

```
$(".plus_x").each(function() {
```